# Почему не от всех переходных глаголов образуются страдательные причастия?

Tags: словообразование, причастия

Я прочитал правило:

> Чтобы образовать страдательное
> причастие настоящего времени, нужно:
> 1) определить спряжение глагола, далее
> добавить (к основе?) соответствующий
> суффикс.

Беру глагол *готовить*, определяю спряжение - второе, добавляю суффикс `-им-`, получается готовимый. Но такого слова нет, интересует вопрос почему? :)

Comment: @AMK1112, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Отсутствие отдельных форм причастий может быть связано не с грамматическими законами, а с традицией, что касается и глагола готовить:

1) Не употребляются формы страдательных причастий **настоящего** времени (суффиксы -ом-, -ем-, -им-) у глаголов:
арестовать, беречь, бить, брать, будить, везти, вертеть, вить, возить, вязать, гладить, глядеть, **готовить**, греть, громить, грузить, грызть, давить, держать, жалеть, жарить, жать, ждать, жечь, звать, знать, иметь, кипятить, класть, клеить, колоть, кормить, красить, лепить, лечить, лить, мести, молоть, мыть, находить, пахать, петь, печь, писать, пилить, пить, полоть, портить, прятать, рвать, резать, рубить, солить, ставить, сторожить, сушить, сыпать, ткать, тушить, тянуть, учить, хоронить, чистить, шептать, шить и др.

2) Отсутствуют формы страдательных причастий **прошедшего** времени у переходных глаголов:
вернуть, достать, заставить (что-то сделать), застать, затмить, лизнуть, миновать, напомнить, облететь, подождать, пожелать, полюбить, приветствовать, пробежать, проводить, проехать, просклонять, проспрягать, разглядеть, толкнуть.

Comment: Спасибо, Людмила, особенно за список глаголов.

Answer (score 0):

Потому что не язык конструировался по правилам, а правила выводились из него.

Вполне может не быть в употреблении каких-то слов. Например, это могло не прижиться за ненадобностью: "готовимый" обед - тот, что готовится в данный момент, и в таких выражениях в процессе его приготовления на него некому сослаться. Да и некогда - пригореть может, если готовящий его пойдёт рассказывать: как же хорош будет готовимый мною обед! И только после он расскажет: это мною готовленный обед, потому такой вкусный :)

Comment: Интересно ^_^ Спасибо!

Comment: Не думаю, что связано со смыслом. Скорее всего,ответ кроется в древних процессах словоизменения глаголов.Видимо, изменилась основа настоящего времени, может, она была на -j-?  -л--(готовить-готовлю).Видимо, всё же связано с изменением класса глаголов. Глагол изменился больше, чем другие части речи, но копаться в древнерусском не хочется, всё забыто.Был бы учебник под рукой, нашла бы ответ,но его нет.

Answer (score 0):

> Беру глагол *готовить,* определяю
>   спряжение - второе, добавляю суффикс
>   -им-, получается *готовимый.* Но такого слова нет...

Почему нет? Есть. К примеру, у Зализняка *(Грамматический словарь русского языка).* Другое дело, что произносится с затруднением и употребляется очень редко (по Зализняку -- *"преимущественно в книжном и возвышенно-архаизирующем стиле"*).

Есть у Крылова *("И гибели познал, готовимые мне…")*, есть у Даля…

Вряд ли кто станет утверждать, что Корней Иванович Чуковский плохо знал русский язык. Хорошо знал! И тем не менее…
См. у него:

[image]

Comment: Его нет чисто условно. Частота употребления такова, что гугл вместо него предлагает только альтернативы. Хотя из похожих по форме такие редкие причастия как "морозимый", "мусолимый" или "славословимый" он находит сразу. Норвежские лингвисты близкое им "морозимый" с удовольствием включили в какую-то исследуемую ими схему словообразования :)

Comment: Alex_ander: "Частота употребления такова, что гугл вместо него предлагает только альтернативы. Хотя из похожих по форме такие редкие причастия как "морозимый"... он находит сразу".===

ЧуднО!!!  Мне Гугл с "морозимый"  показывает всего 23 примера,  в то время как с "готовимый" -- в десять раз больше!